# ¿Cómo realizo un update más de una vez en mongodb usado .updateOne()?

Tags: jsp, mongodb

Estoy usando la base de datos en la nube de mongodb, mlab.com. Pero tengo un problema al realizar la actualización de un documento.

Al parecer al utilizar la instrucción `updateOne()` sólo me actuliza una vez en la base de datos. No lo puedo hacer de manera repetiva.

Estoy creando la página web en un repositorio de maven usando html y jsp.

Este es el código de mi  .jsp

```
MongoClient conexion = new MongoClient(mongoURI);        
MongoDatabase db = conexion.getDatabase("cp_vneonatos");

MongoCollection<Document> coleccion = db.getCollection("estancias");

coleccion.updateOne(and(eq("cedulamadre",cedulamadre), eq("horariom",horariom), eq("fechaingresom",fechaingresom)),
                            and (addtoset("cedulamadre",cedulamadre), addtoset("horariom",horarionuevom), addtoset("fechaingresom",fechaingresomx)));
```

No me sale errores ni nada parecido. Sólo eso de no poder actualizar más de una vez un documento.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. La verdad no conozco de MongoDB, pero yo te recomendaría modificar tu código para crear en un método/función diferente la lógica para enviarle los valores a actualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Al parecer al utilizar la instrucción `updateOne` sólo me actuliza una vez en la base de datos. No lo puedo hacer de manera repetiva.

La función `updateOne` **actualiza la primera ocurrencia** que encuentra de acuerdo a los parámetros que se le han pasado, pero esto no quiere decir que no puedas actualizar un documento las veces que sean necesarias ya que las funciones de MongoDB no mantienen ningún estado que ocasione alguna condición para su ejecución; es como un servicio REST, siempre ejecutará la tarea que se le pida **a no ser que ocurra un error interno**.

En tu caso, es probable que estés actualizando un campo que estás usando como condición en actualizaciones posteriores, por lo que la condición no se cumple para ningún documento y obviamente no realizará ningún update. Puedes saber esto colocando `upsert: true` al objeto de opciones:

```
collection.updateOne(<filter>, <update>, { upsert: true });
```

La opción `upsert` forza a MongoDB a que cree un nuevo documento si no ha sido encontrado ninguno. De esta manera puedes darte cuenta que estás usando un filtro erróneo al actualizar.

Comment: Al parecer la base de datos en mlab no se estaba actualizando correctamente. Realmente no se el por que, pero intente luego hacer la actualización del registro un tiempo mas tarde y mis datos comenzaron a actualizarse correctamente. De igual manera muchas gracias no conocía el upsert. Lo pondré en practica :D